# Google Gears shifts site down in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, mobile-website, google-gears

So added gears functionality into my Mobi Engine, but there is a wierd behavior when viewing the site in Chrome. The HTML gets shifted down by about 15px. All other browsers tested so far does not show the same problem. Also doesn't seem to affect any mobile browsers.

Check here for the symptom. http://cibr8.itell.mobi

I only need gears to post back the user's location (if allowed by the user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what is causing this, but you could drop Gears for the Chrome browser. What Gears used to provide (location & local storage) is now part of HTML 5.  Google have "end of life'd" Gears. Chrome supports HTML5 (up to date versions anyway)

http://gearsblog.blogspot.com/2010/02/hello-html5.html

Comment: This is the component that i used relies on gears. It does the whole WiFi/CellID/GPS lookup thing to return a Lat/Long. Remove it though for now. Was fun to play with in the interim anyway. Tx.